# Energy bar is too soft

Tags: snacks

I'm trying to make a recipe for an energy bar that can keep it's form, doesn't melt in above-average temperature, and doesn't stick to the teeth.

I want to use a minimum amount of ingredients. For nutritional profile I have settled with roasted peanuts and sesame seeds. I use dates to bind them, and coco powder or freeze-dried fruit powder for flavor, for example banana.

I have tried all kinds of date pastes, some are definitely hold form better than others, but the bar still bends in middle under its own weight when holding up it in the air.

What other natural ingredient (no chemical preservatives or sugar powders) I can introduce into the recipe to make the bar dense but soft, and not too gooey?

Comment: Welcome! Can you [edit] your question to include the rough proportion of your ingredients? Have you tried varying the ratio of date paste to cocoa/fruit powder to see what effect that has on consistency?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you need is a powder, you could try a protein powder, or you could use peanut butter powder, which is a good thickener. Chia powder is also a great binder.

Another option would be a gum like xanthan or guar gum.

Heat is another option if you aren't baking these already, heat will drive out moisture and help the mix crystallize.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!

I also read that chia is a good preservative and thickens quite well. Maybe I should try to use it in the recipe.

I'm not keen on using protein powders or gums, but I tried baking the bars for 6 minutes and they definitely hardens. I heard many makers of bars dehydrate them before packing. Maybe this is the way to go.

Comment: You can dehydrate them in your oven if the temperature goes low enough @user69335